# Eclipse -- Manually Install Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ada

I am trying to migrate from Adacore's GPS to the Eclipse based GNATBench. GNATBench is available [here](http://mirrors.cdn.adacore.com/art/ef73b2f9a979dcfc2c8ad8badb5055a73bff333c) for free download, but is packaged as a zip file. I have only installed Eclipse plugins through the marketplace, or through an online repository. I have tried extracting the folder into the Eclipse plugins folder, but it did not work. How do I install this plugin manually through a zip file? Is there another way of getting it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open `Help > Install New Software...` and click `Add` (top right).

In the Add Repository dialog that is shown click `Archive...` and select the zip file you downloaded. Also give the Repository a name. Click OK.

The Available Software dialog should now show you the contents of the zip and you can choose what to install.

Comment: A lot of helpful content you provide ;-)