# Looking for eclipse plugin "cppcheclipse"

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I've been desperately looking for a download of the eclipse plugin cppcheclipse v1.0. Sadly the repo at http://cppcheclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/svn/update has been down for at least a week now...

Could someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by downloading v0.9.9 from the old website and doing a manual install:

https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/cppcheclipse/downloads

How to do a manual install:

[How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

[Eclipse -- Manually Install Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199245/eclipse-manually-install-plugin)